# PHP 404 response header

Tags: php, http, http-headers, http-status-code-404, error-code

I use .htaccess RewriteRules to pass the url to index.php. If the specified page name isn't found in the database, I want my script to throw proper 404 responses.

The way I have tried to achieve this is:

```
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");
```

Analysing the HTTP responses in my browser, the response comes back fine:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

However, I would like to be able to output a friendly 404 page, but anything after the header() function gets disregarded, and anything before ... well ... that'd be stupid.

Can anyone suggest how to output a 404 error message from the script?

Thanks.

Comment: why not just output the friendly error page after header(), using echo for example? From my experience, this method works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure the output (or ErrorDocument) is larger than 512 bytes as to make sure Internet Explorer doesn't display it's own error-page. This is probably why you have experienced any output after the header doesn't get displayed.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . " was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at " . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . " Port 80</address>
</body></html>";
    exit();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So following (in .htaccess)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errordoc.html
```

is not working for you ?

**EDIT:** As you see, you can easy throw 404 in PHP and then catch it in .htaccess.